# Set Locale from App - Back Button Issue

Tags: android, localization

I am working on Language setting on my app. I was able to change the locale from my Main Activity through the use of

```
Resources resources = getResources();
Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
configuration.setLocale(new Locale("ar"));
resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,displayMetrics);
recreate();
```

Everything worked fine but I noticed that the back button did not change its direction to RTL:

[image]

This is my expected behaviour when I set the language to a RTL language:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems it's an emulator. Anyway, do you have this problem on other devices and emulators too?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018281/change-navigation-bar-orientation-rtl-programmatically

Comment: @Mr.Hyde the answer provided is not working.

Comment: Do you have this problem on other devices and emulators too? Preferably with API upper than 17.

Comment: yes. tested on devices with android 5.1.1 (API 22) and 7.1.1 (API 25). My minSdkVersion = 19.

Comment: check this link, It might help you 
https://android.jlelse.eu/rtl-support-on-android-here-is-all-you-need-know-e13f2df512e2

Comment: Did you add this in your application tag in the manifest file? android:supportsRtl="true"

Comment: Yes I have it in my Manifest.

Comment: You need not handle this, the system automatically changes back button location when you change system Language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the navigation bar's direction means that the app will change the `Locale` of the device. Such a thing is similar to setting the device language in the language setting of the device since a `Locale` defines the language and direction (rtl or ltr) of the views to support the language. Since you're only changing the `Locale` of your `Context` in the app, it will **not** affect the `Context` of the other apps on the device and the system apps/components (launcher, navigation bar, status bar, etc...). Hence the navigation bar will not change and stay unaffected by the change in your app.

Furthermore, to alter the device `Locale` or any other configuration (font, font size, display metrics, rotation, etc..), the app would need the `SET_CONFIGURATION` permission to do so. Although it is not stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CHANGE_CONFIGURATION), the `SET_CONFIGURATION` permission can only be given automatically to system apps like the language and display settings. I haven't seen if it can be requested from the user by a third party app but I believe that it cannot be as most of the times in the development of my apps, the permission was being granted using `adb shell pm grant` command in the command line. Usually I would do that during my tests since my apps also support other languages and would want to make sure that the app performs well in such cases, hence I'd grant it the permission in the command line and let it to change the locale of the device from within the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call this method when you set arabic language:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void forceRTLIfSupported()
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){

      //HERE CHECK CONDITION FOR YOUR LANGUAGE if it is AR then
      //change if it is english then don't

      getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);


    }
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. but this answer might be a good solution in other cases. +1

Comment: Have tried that on emulator lollipop and nougat, it didn't work. @RajeshKoshti s-g, could you provide us some **full** screenshots showing that the code worked and changed the direction of the nav bar?

Comment: ok will try it in emulator when i will get some time and provide you screenshots @ahasbini

Comment: My friend had used this and it worked, may be some specific case

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the navigation bar (and other parts of the OS, like the Settings), is not related to an app. A user can have a LTR OS with a RTL app. thus changing your app's locale and direction does not affect the underlying OS and the user has to change it manually.